# How to print specyfic String without using double quotes nor single quotes?

Tags: java

My task is to display specified text e.g. "dummy123". But the problem is that I can't use neither " nor ' and even no integers to do something like that. As I know in Java is no preprocessor like

```
#define W(x) #x;
```

How to have code like that without quotes:

```
public class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       System.out.println("dummy123");
    }
}
```

Comment: how about character manipulation ?

Comment: Can you cheat and have the user input the "dummy123" text from console, or perhaps read it from a text file (technically not source code), store it in string var and just print it? Technically there are no quotes nor use of casting from int to char :P.

Comment: So, do you want the output to literally be "dummy123" including the quotes? Or is the problem that you want to output dummy123 to the console without using any quotes in your code? Perhaps you could quote the exact details of the problem instead of summarizing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an enum

```
public enum myEnum{
   dummy123
}
```

Then use the .toString

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String x = Test.dummy123.toString();
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Output: dummy123

Answer (score 3):

Determine what the Unicode codes are for each of the characters in the `String` you want.  Then create a `char[]` and cast your numeric Unicode codes to `char` to initialize your `char[]`.  E.g., `'d'` is `(char) 100`.  Then you can create a `String` from the `char[]`.  This uses no double-quote or single-quote characters in the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but another problem is that I can't use also numbers:(.

Comment: You should have specified that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In java a char is interchangeable with an Int. You could just use a technique like:

```
System.out.print(Character.toChars(X));
```

Where X is the integer value of the character in question :D

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars%28int%29 for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but another problem is that I can't use also numbers:(.